# How to search values using vlookup based on multiple columns and not creating any additional helper columns?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a table DATA in which some customer IDs are present. Based on their asset type, their transaction value is present. 
In another RESULT sheet, I need to lookup what is the transaction value for a particular customer and the asset type.

The data table is as shown  below on the left and the result sheet is shown on the right. Now for a particular customer 1301, the transaction value for ASSET_CODE_1 is 51. So the same value needs to be populated in cell B2 in sheet RESULT.

I have searched on the web but I am not able to find a satisfactory solution to this. Some people recommended using & operator in vlookup search value but it didnt work.

[image]

Is there anyway I can achieve this without creating any additional columns in either sheets ? The data is randomly sorted in my original sheet (unlike in this sample here)

Comment: You should look at using index() with match() as they will allow the indexing of any column in the range, while vlookup only indexes the leftmost column.

Comment: Actually looking up the data with an INDEX/MATCH/MATCH would be fairly simple. Is your cust_Id column a static list? Or do they need to pull through to the RESULT sheet dynamically. Doing that without a helper column would be the tricky part.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is to pull all the distinct cust_Id's through to the results sheet.
You can do this with a MINIFS formula:

```
MINIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,">"&MAX($G$2:$G2))
```

This gets the lowest cust_Id, and then gets next highest, then the next, etc.
When you run out of cust_Id's, it will return 0. you can check for that and replace the 0 with "", by wrapping the MINIFS in an IF:

[image]

The next issue is to pull the data through to the correct cell. You can do this with an INDEX/MATCH/INDEX:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(1,INDEX(($F3=$A$2:$A$10)*(G$2=$B$2:$B$10),0,1),0))
```

This works the same as an INDEX/MATCH, except that inside the MATCH, you use a second index to check for the multiple criteria:

[image]

I hope this makes sense. If you need me to clarify anything, please let me know.
I have done the DATA and RESULT on the same sheet for simplicity but it should be fairly easy for you to split it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your *TR_VALUE* is always a number, and your *custid* and *asset_code* values are **always** a unique combination, then just use a `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(DATA!$C:$C, DATA!$A:$A, $A2, DATA!$B:$B, Column()-1)
```

Or, I guess, just use a PivotTable.